# Why does my function only work with lvalues?

Tags: c++, string, rvalue, lvalue, std-ranges

I have a function that returns a lowercase string:

```
constexpr auto string_to_lower_case(const std::string& string) {
    return string
        | std::views::transform(std::tolower)
        | std::views::transform([](const auto& ascii) { return static_cast<char>(ascii); });
}
```

and I expect that function return the same resultat when i will pass `"SOME"` or `const std::string some("SOME")`, but it's not. When I try to print out a result of `string_to_lower_case("SOME")`, I retrieve an empty console (the output of `string_to_lower_case(some)` is correct)

```
const std::string some("SOME");
for (const auto& ch : string_to_lower_case(some))
    std::cout << ch;
```

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531431/passing-a-char-array-to-a-function-that-expects-a-const-stdstring-reference). The call with the char-array creates a temporary, that is gone when you want to output it

Comment: Your function returns a view onto the argument

Comment: Cannot reproduce in [GCC/Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/of85d4GKv).

Comment: @康桓瑋 Add `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and it'll be more fun :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some issues:

- The temporary `std::string` that is created when you call the function with a `char[]` goes out of scope when the function returns and is then destroyed. The `view` you return can't be used to iterate over the string after that.
- You take the address of `std::tolower` which isn't allowed since it's not on the list of [*Designated addressable functions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Designated_addressable_functions).
- You don't convert the `char` used with `std::tolower` to `unsigned char` first. If `char` has a negative value, it'll cause *undefined behavior*.
- Your second `transform`ation seems redundant.

An alternative is to return an actual `std::string` instead of a `view`:

```
constexpr std::string string_to_lower_case(const std::string& string) {
    auto view = string
              | std::views::transform([](char ch){
                    return static_cast<char>(std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)));
                });
    return {view.begin(), view.end()};
}
```